# Unable create questions on recently joined stack exchange sites

Tags: support, bug, user-accounts

Yesterday I created a Cross Validated account and when I tried to post it said "An error occurred submitting the question" with no further details. I now tried to post a question on Cognitive Sciences and it hung loading a captcha. Is anyone else having these problems or know how to fix them?

This happened around 1am Pacific time January 14.

[image: an error occurred]

This is still happening right now

[image: hanging]

and the progress indicator keeps going and hangs.

I'm using Firefox 26.0

Comment: Ugh. If there's more than one reason that error would show, I wish we'd put some kind of code at the end of it, I dread that particular message. Can you give your browser details and the approximate time it happened? That'll help us dig into it.

Comment: I checked the error logs, nothing in particular I could find. I also got a captcha, which worked... Are you by any chance using https everywhere or some similar browser add-in?

Comment: I am using https everywhere and ghostery but I tried disabling them and no change.